# to get max number of singer in a city

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
Singer              
SingerId    SingerName  City    DOB Gender
1   A   Hyderabad   14-Apr-65   M
2   B   Chennai 25-May-84   M
3   C   Bangalore   14-Sep-78   F
4   D   Hyderabad   17-Jan-70   M
5   E   Hyderabad   18-Mar-87   F
6   F   Bangalore   23-Aug-75   F
```

question)))    List the City where maximum number of singers present

hi guys can you help me to find out maximun number of singer present city i tried it not yet resolved help me

i want only output of city having max no of singers please help me to get it resolved

Comment: You indicated both Mysql and Oracle ... which is it ? it can't be both .. O.o

Comment: Group by the city and sort by the count

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT City, COUNT(SingerName)
FROM Singer
GRIUOP BY City
HAVING COUNT (SingerName) = (SELECT MAX(SingerName) FROM Singer)
```

Comment: its ok buddy i want to get only hyd as outupt becz it is having the maximun no of singer in that city

Comment: its false buddy we need to get max no of singers in a city                                                 i resolved it actual query is                   select city,count(city) from singer group by city having count(city) = (select max(count(city)) from singer group by city)

Comment: Oops i missed your requirement.